# Azure AD B2C changes to propagate to downstream applications

Tags: c#, azure, active-directory, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-b2c

I tried to search for the answer to this but no luck.

Is there any way that direct changes to the user information in Azure AD B2C be propagated to the downstream applications?

For example, if the user first name "John" is changed to "Joe" in the Azure AD B2C portal by the administrator, it will automatically trigger something that will send something to our web application so it will pickup that change and update the corresponding table values for it.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I don't think that would be possible. Would be happy to be corrected. A little more detail on the web application use cases would help in suggesting alternative methods like the Microsoft Graph API

Comment: Currently there is no push model for updates, but you could get this info from MS Graph API and use a cache in front of it so you don't call it every time. Another choice is a scheduled job that syncs your table at some intervals.

Comment: Thank you for the responses and tips. We will just not allow direct updates to the Azure AD B2C tenant so the information will not get out of sync. A scheduled job via MS Graph API is also a good option for making sure that they are.

Answer (score 1):

You can access the audit logs for the Azure AD B2C directory using [the Azure Active Directory audit API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/active-directory-reporting-api-audit-reference).

You can filter on the **activityType** field to retrieve activities, such as updates, that have occurred on the user records:

`https://graph.windows.net/contoso.com/activities/audit?api-version=beta&$filter=activityType eq 'User'`